# How can I implement (WaitUntilEvent) in c#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events

I have looked at the answer in
[How to block until an event is fired in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745848/how-to-block-until-an-event-is-fired-in-c-sharp)

unfortunately, it does not provide a full answer that I can incorporate or make it work for my situation.

I am building an app that talks to a remote equipment through Serial port.

There is a protocol to be used whenever communication is established. It goes like this:

```
PC:       Are you ready?
Hardware: Yes go ahead!
PC:       Here is my question <insert question here>
PC:       Did you get it?
Hardware: Yes, I got your question. Let me think
...
some time later
...    
Hardware: Are you ready?
PC:       yes, go ahead
Hardware: Here is your answer: <insert answer here>
```

I am currently using Sleep(1000) in-between messages to make sure the hardware did receive the message. But the problem is 1 second might be too much in a lot of cases. Because the hardware can reply as soon as 20 milliseconds, and at worst 800 milliseconds. I need to trigger an event whenever the hardware says it is ready, or when it asks if PC is ready.

Here is what I am hoping to do:

```
private event EventHandler HardwareSaysItIsReadyEvent;
private event EventHandler HardwareAsksIfPcIsReadyEvent;

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
     SetUpComPort();

     HardwareSaysItIsReadyEvent += HardwareIsReadyEvent;
     HardwareAsksIfPcIsReady    += IsPcReadyEvent;
     
     await AskHardwareIfReadyAndWaitForAnswer();
     // assume the hardware will always answer with YES, but it may take time
     
     await AskHardwareQuestion();
     await AskHardwareIfQuestionWasReceivedAndWaitForAnswer();

}
private void SetUpComPort() { ... }
private async Task AskHardwareIfReadyAndWaitForAnswer() 
{ 
/* I can send data to the hardware but how can I force 
   The process to wait here until the event is triggered, 
   or 1000 milliseconds expire?   
*/ 
}
private async Task AskHardwareIfQuestionWasReceivedAndWaitForAnswer() { ... }

private void HardwareIsReadyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // let the awaiter know so it may proceed to the question part
}

private void IsPcReadyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // send a YES confirmation then let awaiter know so that it may proceed to receive answer
}
```

How can I suspend execution (without blocking UI) until a certain timeout, or an event is triggered?

*Edit:* I know how to trigger events based on text received from hardware, I did not show that part in my code. I don't need help triggering the event. I just need help telling program to send something and waiting for a reply or quitting after 1 second.

*Edit 2:* I am using `SerialPort` builtin class to do the talking with the hardware, and am already hooking up data received event in case the hardware is talking to the PC. That is how I am firing the events `ServerSaysItIsReady` and `ServerIsAsking...`

Comment: The question you linked has an example with `TaskCompletionSource`, why it doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: @Evk the answer does not provide a timeout limit, plus, it works when you have one thing to wait for. Will I need an array of `tcs` or can I use the same one for every message?

Comment: If processing is sequential then one is enough: you'll create new one every time before sending message, then send message, then await completion source Task. As for timeout: use `await Task.WhenAny(source.Task, Task.Delay(1000))`. It returns the first completed task which is either main task (then timeout was not reached), or Task.Delay task (then it's timeout).

Comment: @Evk Would you care to elaborate your comment as an answer so that I may accept it, or should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your process is sequential (only one "question" at a time, always followed by event) then you can use single `TaskComletionSource` to achieve your goal:

```
private TaskCompletionSource _reply;
private async Task AskHardwareIfReadyAndWaitForAnswer() {
    _reply = new TaskCompletionSource();
    // now send a message to the hardware
    // use separate task to indicate timeout
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(1000);
    // if timeoutTask completed first - then you waited for 1 second with no reply
    bool isTimeout = await Task.WhenAny(_reply.Task, timeoutTask) == timeoutTask;
    if (isTimeout) {
        _reply = null;
    }
}

private void HardwareIsReadyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // signal
    _reply?.TrySetResult();
}
```